# Connect-MgGraph: Unable to find type & The browser based authentication dialog failed to complete. Reason: The server or proxy was not found

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api

We have an application that calls Connect-MgGraph. This cmdlet tries to launch a Microsoft authentication dialog, however it has been failing in a specific customer environment with the following stack trace:

```
The following information was included with the event:
Timestamp: 8/10/2022 1:40:47 PM Message: Error creating O365 application: Fail to add application System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: Unable to find type [Microsoft.Graph.PowerShell.Models.IMicrosoftGraphAccessPackageAutomaticRequestSettings].
   at Microsoft.Graph.PowerShell.Runtime.PowerShell.GetScriptCmdlet.ProcessRecord()
   at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: Unable to find type [Microsoft.Graph.PowerShell.Models.IMicrosoftGraphAccessPackageAutomaticRequestSettings].
   at Microsoft.Graph.PowerShell.Runtime.PowerShell.GetScriptCmdlet.ProcessRecord()
   at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord()<---

---> (Inner Exception #1) System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: Unable to find type [Microsoft.Graph.PowerShell.Models.IMicrosoftGraphAccessPackageAutomaticRequestSettings].
   at Microsoft.Graph.PowerShell.Runtime.PowerShell.GetScriptCmdlet.ProcessRecord()
   at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord()<---

---> (Inner Exception #2) System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: Unable to find type [Microsoft.Graph.PowerShell.Models.IMicrosoftGraphAccessPackageAutomaticRequestSettings].
   at Microsoft.Graph.PowerShell.Runtime.PowerShell.GetScriptCmdlet.ProcessRecord()
   at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord()<---

---> (Inner Exception #3) System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: Unable to find type [Microsoft.Graph.PowerShell.Models.IMicrosoftGraphAccessPackageAutomaticRequestSettings].
   at Microsoft.Graph.PowerShell.Runtime.PowerShell.GetScriptCmdlet.ProcessRecord()
   at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord()<---

---> (Inner Exception #4) MSAL.Desktop.4.29.0.0.MsalClientException: 
    ErrorCode: authentication_ui_failed
Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalClientException: The browser based authentication dialog failed to complete. Reason: The server or proxy was not found.
   at Microsoft.Graph.PowerShell.Authentication.Cmdlets.ConnectMgGraph.<ProcessRecordAsync>d__56.MoveNext()<---

---> (Inner Exception #5) System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication needed, call Connect-MgGraph.
   at Microsoft.Graph.PowerShell.Authentication.Helpers.HttpHelpers.GetGraphHttpClient(InvocationInfo invocationInfo, IAuthContext authContext)
   at Microsoft.Graph.PowerShell.Module.BeforeCreatePipeline(InvocationInfo invocationInfo, HttpPipeline& pipeline)
   at Microsoft.Graph.PowerShell.Module.CreatePipeline(InvocationInfo invocationInfo, String parameterSetName)
   at Microsoft.Graph.PowerShell.Cmdlets.GetMgServicePrincipal_List1.<ProcessRecordAsync>d__84.MoveNext()<---

---> (Inner Exception #6) System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication needed, call Connect-MgGraph.
   at Microsoft.Graph.PowerShell.Authentication.Helpers.HttpHelpers.GetGraphHttpClient(InvocationInfo invocationInfo, IAuthContext authContext)
   at Microsoft.Graph.PowerShell.Module.BeforeCreatePipeline(InvocationInfo invocationInfo, HttpPipeline& pipeline)
   at Microsoft.Graph.PowerShell.Module.CreatePipeline(InvocationInfo invocationInfo, String parameterSetName)
   at Microsoft.Graph.PowerShell.Cmdlets.GetMgServicePrincipal_List1.<ProcessRecordAsync>d__84.MoveNext()<---

---> (Inner Exception #7) System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication needed, call Connect-MgGraph.
   at Microsoft.Graph.PowerShell.Authentication.Helpers.HttpHelpers.GetGraphHttpClient(InvocationInfo invocationInfo, IAuthContext authContext)
   at Microsoft.Graph.PowerShell.Module.BeforeCreatePipeline(InvocationInfo invocationInfo, HttpPipeline& pipeline)
   at Microsoft.Graph.PowerShell.Module.CreatePipeline(InvocationInfo invocationInfo, String parameterSetName)
   at Microsoft.Graph.PowerShell.Cmdlets.GetMgServicePrincipal_List1.<ProcessRecordAsync>d__84.MoveNext()<---

---> (Inner Exception #8) System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication needed, call Connect-MgGraph.
   at Microsoft.Graph.PowerShell.Authentication.Helpers.HttpHelpers.GetGraphHttpClient(InvocationInfo invocationInfo, IAuthContext authContext)
   at Microsoft.Graph.PowerShell.Module.BeforeCreatePipeline(InvocationInfo invocationInfo, HttpPipeline& pipeline)
   at Microsoft.Graph.PowerShell.Module.CreatePipeline(InvocationInfo invocationInfo, String parameterSetName)
   at Microsoft.Graph.PowerShell.Cmdlets.GetMgServicePrincipal_List1.<ProcessRecordAsync>d__84.MoveNext()<---

---> (Inner Exception #9) System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication needed, call Connect-MgGraph.
   at Microsoft.Graph.PowerShell.Authentication.Helpers.HttpHelpers.GetGraphHttpClient(InvocationInfo invocationInfo, IAuthContext authContext)
   at Microsoft.Graph.PowerShell.Module.BeforeCreatePipeline(InvocationInfo invocationInfo, HttpPipeline& pipeline)
   at Microsoft.Graph.PowerShell.Module.CreatePipeline(InvocationInfo invocationInfo, String parameterSetName)
   at Microsoft.Graph.PowerShell.Cmdlets.NewMgApplication_CreateExpanded1.<ProcessRecordAsync>d__176.MoveNext()<---

---> (Inner Exception #10) System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication needed, call Connect-MgGraph.
   at Microsoft.Graph.PowerShell.Authentication.Helpers.HttpHelpers.GetGraphHttpClient(InvocationInfo invocationInfo, IAuthContext authContext)
   at Microsoft.Graph.PowerShell.Module.BeforeCreatePipeline(InvocationInfo invocationInfo, HttpPipeline& pipeline)
   at Microsoft.Graph.PowerShell.Module.CreatePipeline(InvocationInfo invocationInfo, String parameterSetName)
   at Microsoft.Graph.PowerShell.Cmdlets.NewMgServicePrincipal_CreateExpanded1.<ProcessRecordAsync>d__198.MoveNext()<---
```

We tried running the Connect-MgGraph cmdlet directly from powershell and immediately got the error  "The browser based authentication dialog failed to complete. Reason: The server or proxy was not found."

Other troubleshooting steps we have tried:

- Ensured no proxy is being used
- Disabled firewall
- Made MS Edge and IE default browser
- Disabled pop-up blocker in IE settings
- Used Fiddler to try and see network errors but no traffic is sent to
  MS
- Asked the customer to enable basic authentication in M365, but request was denied

At first, we were not getting the exception about the missing type in the stack trace, only the exception about the browser based authentication dialog failing to complete. I am not sure what caused the extra exception to suddenly start being reported.

Since we confirmed the browser dialog exception is occurring directly in powershell, it seems to be something environmental, but I am at a loss as to what to try next. I also could not find any information about IMicrosoftGraphAccessPackageAutomaticRequestSettings or how it can be a missing type.

Answer (score 0):

This normally indicates a browser or firewall configuration issue on your machine, please try first with Disconnect-MgGraph and then run Connect-MgGraph , it will again ask for the credential, provide the credentials and hope it will work fine

if not work , check similar issue - https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-powershell/issues/641

Thanks